# php curl hide window location

Tags: php, window.location, php-curl

I am trying to **php curl** one of my domain through localhost and another site of mine. I have put histats counter widget, and it is showing my localhost address. 
here is the picture of it

[histats showing my window locahost location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzqkZ.png)

the code that i use :

```
    function curl($url) {
    $options = Array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,  
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0", 
        CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false 
    );

    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $data;  
}



$data_page = curl("http://example.com"); 

print $data_page;
```

but if i use DOM loadHTMLFile, the counter stats didn't show anything.

what i have tried is to edit the HTTP Headers, HTTP Referer, but it still couldn't hide my localhost site location. Can i do it with php curl without the stats counter showing my localhost or counting stats on it?

Comment: Disable the counter stats script for localhost. You can't fake a forward address to the counter as it's script is a third party code which you can't modify,

Comment: my point is = 'is there any way to spoof?'.. since i had been using the stats for long time..and DOM can hide it i believe php curl probably can do the same

Comment: i think the only way to do it with php curl is to preg_replace the script tag. when the script is loaded on browser, it will look into my windows location.

Comment: CURL can't execute javascript so most likely your "stats script" is an image file usually a 1x1 pixel gif file. you will need to block that code in your main page by only showing it when the `HTTP_HOST` is not `localhost`.